# Python using result of function for Regular Expression Substitution

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of text, and for every regex match, I want to substitute that match with the return value from another function.  The argument to this function is of course the matched text.

I have been having trouble trying to come up with a one pass solution to this problem.  It feels like it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> def dashrepl(matchobj):
...     if matchobj.group(0) == '-': return ' '
...     else: return '-'
>>> re.sub('-{1,2}', dashrepl, 'pro----gram-files')
'pro--gram files'
```

Comment: Damn, I just assumed that it could be a string in that function

Answer (score 0):

Python-agnostic:  Match everything before and everything after your text to replace.

```
/^(.*?)(your regexp to match)(.*)$/
```

Then you have the next before and after the text you're going to replace.  The rest is easy -- just insert the result of your function between the two strings.

Comment: The OP said "for every match", so you described only half of the algorithm. In any case, the appropriate answer has been given and chosen.